# PyCaret Classification - "finalize_model" gives very different results than "compare_models"

Tags: classification, pycaret, overfitting-underfitting

Toolset Versions:

```
python: 3.10.13 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:24:38) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
pycaret: 3.1.0
```

[Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMNSn.png)

First post - please be gentle if I don't provide all the info needed. ;)

I'm using pycaret to perform a binary classification.  Here is my setup:

```
exp = ClassificationExperiment()
exp.setup(filtered_train, target = 'diseaseweek', fix_imbalance=True, log_experiment = True,
          experiment_name = 'exp1 - full feature set, PCA',
          normalize=True, remove_multicollinearity=True, pca=True, pca_components=0.95, session_id = 123)
```

[PyCaret Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZB0U.png)

And here are the results of "compare_models."  I've left the holdout split as the PyCaret default.

[compare_models() results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0kLm.png)

This is the resulting ROC curve:

[Initial ROC curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z448f.png)

I finalize the model:
[Model finalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93lcp.png)

And get this resulting ROC curve:
[ROC curve after finalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A82D.png)

Any guidance on the levers I can pull to reduce the overfitting I'm seeing?  Thanks!

I ran a PyCaret classification model using the default 10-fold stratified cross validation, and the default 70:30 holdout split and saw good cross validation performance.  But when I finalized the model across the entire dataset, the performance of the final model is greatly reduced.  I'm not sure what actions I can take to reduce the overfitting.

I should add that I get very similar results with a tuned version of the same model.  (Tuned on 50 iterations.)